# Python BeautifulSoup TypeError : find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def read_news(url) :
    news_detail = {}
    news_detail['title'] = link.find("h1", class_='post_title')
    news_detail['content'] = link.find("span", class_='news_text')
    print(news_detail)

url = 'https://www.baki-xeber.com'
r = requests.get(url)
bs4 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
elements = bs4.find_all("div", class_='post_content_without_pic')
for element in elements:
    link = url + element.find("a").get("href")
    read_news(link)
```

when i run code it gives this:

```
TypeError : find() takes no keyword arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Thanks to @slothrop, indeed no `built-in function`.

You are calling [`find` method of the `str` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) in the following lines, instead of a `bs4` method.

```
news_detail['title'] = link.find("h1", class_='post_title')
news_detail['content'] = link.find("span", class_='news_text')
```

Based on your code it should look more like this:

```
def read_news(url) :
    r = requests.get(url)
    link = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    
    news_detail = {}
    news_detail['title'] = link.find("h1", class_='post_title')
    news_detail['content'] = link.find("span", class_='news_text')
    print(news_detail)
```